# Pandas set_value() insert float behaves weird

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Our intern wrote a code working with pandas and complained he cannot locate error, but results do not match expectations. Surprisingly, I could not help him either, because I ran into some **unexpected behaviour** using pandas `dataframe.set_value()`

I thinned the problem into this:
Inserting float values above 110 or so produces incorrect negative values in dataframe.

I extracted important values into a list of tuples.

Structure: `[(index_of_df_insert_row, float_value_to_insert), ...]`

Here is the important code snippet:

```
print(replace_values)

for index, value in replace_values:
    grouped_to_data.set_value(index, "Realized_Time_Indirect", value)
    print(value + " > ")
    print(grouped_to_data.iloc[index]["Realized_Time_Indirect"])
    print()
```

And here is the sample output:

```
5.6 >
5

8.5 >
8

43.0 >
43

23.0 >
23

<<<<<<<<<<< WHY? >>>>>>>>>>>

147.5 >
-109

<<<<<<<<<<< WHY? >>>>>>>>>>>

28.0 >
28

28.5 >
28

39.32 >
39

17.0 >
17

86.30000000000001 >
86

58.5 >
58
```

Comment: set_value is deprecated in current version of pandas.  Secondly, set_value uses index labels, then iloc is using index positions, are they the same?   Are you sure you don't want something like `print(group_to_data.loc[index,"Realized_Time_Indirect"])`?

Comment: How easily I skipped that in docs... Thanks, I am not using the function in my own code, I will mark this as a correct answer as soon as he confirms it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `set_value` is deprecated in the current version of pandas. Secondly, `set_value` uses index labels, then `iloc` is using index positions, are they the same in your dataframe?  If your index is not stating with zero, then you are potentially looking at different rows.

Let's try something like this instead:

```
print(group_to_data.loc[index,"Realized_Time_Indirect"])
```